# accidentally deleted *some* of /var, but have an old backup, how can I fix this?

Tags: 12.04, backup, delete

I'm on 12.04LTS.

I had an old OS disk mounted at `/media/backup/`, and I was converting it to use as a backup disk. I accidentally ran `sudo rm -rf /var/` rather than `sudo rm -rf var/`, and deleted *some* of my `/var/` before catching my mistake with `^C`.

I recopied across some files from `/media/backup/var/` using `cp -na /media/backup/var/specific_path/* /var/specific_path/`, mainly doing the obvious here (folders in `/var/` which had fewer files than in `/media/backup/var/` for example). A few things were obviously not working:

- Totem complained from the command line that it was unable to connect to jack (this is important as the machine is a HTPC running mythtv)
- some programs complained that there is no `/var/lib/dbus/machine_id`, and this folder and file was not recreated on reboot (I had expected it might be)

Once I felt I had done enough, I tried a reboot.

The tty7 fails, and I get a text-based login. Do I need to copy across some gdm files? My old installation had been gradually upgraded to 12.04LTS from 8.04LTS originally. I'm guessing its `var/` has some legacy folders that I don't need to reproduce in my `/var/`. For example it has a `var/lib/gdm/` folder, but `/var/lib/` doesn't. Then again I thought gdm had been deprecated?

Can I do a 'repair' using an installation CD, or is there a way to use my backup to repair the rest?

#### UPDATE

`cp /media/backup/var/lib/gdm/* /var/lib/gdm/` got me to the point where I can boot to the desktop. I'm now in a less critical state, but my question above still stands: is there a way to detect what should be missing, or force some sort of intelligent `dpkg-reconfigure` for just those packages with missing files?

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach will be to reinstall and use the backup to transfer your data to the new install.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I realise that it's the obvious solution, but I'm reticent to resort to this due to the lengthy setup time of this machine. Although I have adequate backups, I don't have the space to backup all the media on this htpc, so this is a difficult response. Anyway, as you can see above, I've managed to get to the desktop now, so I'm hoping there's also less need to be so drastic.